# Perl GetOptions Function

Tags: perl, perl-module

My Perl Script retrieves the argument in the below way.   Have Getoptions function to retrieve the command line arguments.

```
./test.pl  -mode report -writeid 12 13 23......
```

> ```
> $rc=GetOptions( 'mode=s' => \$cmdParams{mode}
>            ,'writeid:i{1,}' => \@writeid
>            ,'h|?|help'  => \$help
>           );
> ```

The problem is when i have alphanumeric characters in the writeid option it's not failing.  Writeid is defined as integer ( i{1,}) and it can receive 1 to many values.  It doesn't fail when i have alphanumeric character in the second value. 
   ./test.pl  -mode report -writeid 12 A3 23......

What is the workaround i can do?

Comment: For starters, you could show us which of the myriad of standard Getopt::* modules from CPAN you are using.  And most likely, it is saying `12` is the (only) numeric option, leaving the `A3` and `23` as non-option ('filename') arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using the GetOptions function I assume you are using GetOpts::Long, the trouble with the "{1,}" one or more quantity in the option specification is that once you've successfully matched an integer, you've "succeeded". if you removed the quantitive spec and just ran with 'writeid:i' => \@writeid, each write_id would have to be preceded by the flag on the command line and so you would get an error state when it failed to parse.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info. I dont want to specify -writeid 1   -writeid 2 -writeid 3.  I want to have -writeid 1 22 33.  What workaround i can do to resolve this

Comment: Perhaps make the flag -w as -w 12 -w 13 -w 14 would be easier to write?
Sorry I can't offer anything more useful, but without hacking the GetOpts module, I don't see what else you can do :(